# Mono error reading valid XML: "Read by order only possible for encoded/bare format"

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, xmlreader

When reading [this valid XML](http://pastebin.com/XHKVuEkL) with Mono's `System.Xml.XmlReader` I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Read by order only possible for encoded/bare format
  at System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap.GetElement (Int32 index) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList, Boolean readBySoapOrder) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstanceMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstance (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObjectElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList, Boolean readBySoapOrder) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstanceMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstance (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping rootMap) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What is the problem?

What does `Read by order only possible for encoded/bare format` mean in the first place?

*Monodevelop 2.8.6.3 on Ubuntu 2012.04 running platform Mono / .NET 3.5

Mono JIT compiler 2.10.8.1*

Comment: Can you show little example where you getting error?

Comment: @Reniuz: It is actually in the source code of the open source library "DotCMIS". I will try to prepare a smaller reproducible snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono crashes on `<xsd:choice>`

See https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2907

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the patch that fixes this problem. It is for trunk version (3.0.?).
If you don't want to touch user's mono, you can simply copy new System.Xml.dll to folder where your program resides. Mono will use your dll instead of user's.

The patch is attached to this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2907

Comment: Great! Actually I am trying to apply the patch right now, but `cd mcs/class/System.XML; patch --dry-run -p1 < ~/Downloads/roman.patch` says `can't find file to patch at input line 6`... which is strange because my current directory contains `System.Xml.Serialization`.

Comment: I made this:

`rzavalov@rzavalov-pc:~$ cd ~/Desktop/System.Xml.Serialization/
rzavalov@rzavalov-pc:~/Desktop/System.Xml.Serialization$ patch --dry-run -p1 -i serialization.patch 
patching file XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs
patching file XmlTypeMapping.cs
`

Put patch into System.Xml.Serialization and cd there too.